# Spring injection on current context for autowire doesnt work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, autowired

I've got problem when I used autowire in my Quartz job. I see that the problem is because the job created by Quartz not Spring, I've used SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); on the first line of execute in my job. 
**The strange thing is, It run fine in my localhost, but when I deployed it in the server it wont autowired and the injection cannot be done, so the service is null**, I got this message

```
"Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of
MeterReadingJob: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web
application. Proceeding without injection."
```

from SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.

I've already match java,and tomcat between my localhost and the server but it still throw same error.

This is my ApplicationListener

```
@Component
public class QuartzInitializerListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>
{
    @Autowired
    private JobService jobService;

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Starting The Event :"+event.getApplicationContext().getDisplayName());
        if(event.getApplicationContext().getParent() == null){
            jobService.meterReadingJob();
        }
    }


}
```

this is the MeterReadingJob class:

```
@Component
public class MeterReadingJob implements Job  {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private TransactionService trxSvc; //This one doesnt autowired correctly

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); //work on localhost only..

        MapTbl mapTbl = (MapTbl)jec.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get("mapTbl");
        System.out.println("SERVICE: "+trxSvc);
        String trxId = trxSvc.validTxIdWithS(4);
        ......
    }
```

this is web.xml for the listener

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

this is my scheduler service method for the meter reading job

```
/*
     * Meter reading schedule for all mapped meter
     */
    public void meterReadingJob() {
        List<MapTbl> mapTbls = mapTblDao.findAll();
        try {
            if(scheduler.isShutdown()){
                scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
            }
            for(MapTbl mapTbl : mapTbls){       
                if(mapTbl.getInterval()!=0){
                    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(MeterReadingJob.class)
                            .withIdentity( mapTbl.getMapId().toString(), "MeterReading").build();

                    job.getJobDataMap().put("mapTbl", mapTbl);

                    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                            .withIdentity( mapTbl.getMapId().toString(), "MeterReading")
                            .withSchedule(
                                SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                                    .withIntervalInMilliseconds(mapTbl.getInterval())
                                    .repeatForever())
                            .startNow()
                            .build();
                        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
                }
            }
            if(mapTbls !=null && mapTbls.size()>0 && !scheduler.isStarted()){
                scheduler.start();
            }
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

It run smoothly in my localhost, but in my server the service always null [not autowired]

Is there anything that I missed so it wont run in my server?
Im using apache tomcat 7.0.42 jdk 7 springframework 3.2.0

Comment: Are you starting Tomcat the same locally and on the server?  For instance, are you running Tomcat within Eclipse locally but starting it through the start script remote?  Are you packaging and deploying the same way?  Is Tomcat configured the same, with the same libraries in the same place?  Something is different, you just need to exhaust all possibilities.

Comment: There's not enough information. For instance who does create `MeterReadingJob` and how is your context starting.

Comment: Im starting tomcat from my STS in local but deploy manually in server. The lib is in the war so I think all lib same.

Comment: The one that start MeterReadingJob is jobService from QuartzInitializerListener it start immediately after the webapp run at the first event [root event]

Comment: Thanks to @StéphaneNicoll you make me check again my code about the scheduler and realized its in static attribute, change it to nonstatic and solved the problem.